# two factor authentication on django

Tags: python, django, two-factor-authentication

I would like to add two factor authentication to my django project. I made some research and found two libraries ([django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) and [drf-pyotp](https://github.com/inforian/drf-pyotp)), but both of them have very little documentation, and my problem is that i really don't know how to implement the library on my already existing project.

Are there other widely used libraries for this? Is there a tutorial or a example that i can use in order to understand it better, in order to implement my own version? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this topic as well, and have started working on my own implementation.

The Authy service from Twilio seems interesting: https://www.twilio.com/authy